# Select first date in which an event happen for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a series of Ids, some of them activate a product on certain month and that product remains activated for an X period of time, while others do not activate the product.

I want to create a column which indicates in which month the user activates the product or a NULL if the user doesn't activate it.

I've tried using a partition like the following:

```
SELECT id, fl_testdrive, month_dt,
CASE WHEN fl_testdrive = 1 then min(month_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month_dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) else 0 end as month_testdrive
FROM Table_1
```

However, when I try this solution, in the column month_testdrive, I do not obtain the first month in which the user appears, indepently of if he/she activated that product in that month or on a later one.

This is what I get with my query

```
Id   flag_testdrive   month_dt   month_testdrive
1         0               1            1
1         0               2            1
1         1               3            1
1         1               4            1
2         0               2            0
2         0               3            0
3         1               4            4
3         1               5            4
```

What I'd expect:

```
Id   flag_testdrive   month_dt   month_testdrive
1         0               1            3
1         0               2            3
1         1               3            3
1         1               4            3
2         0               2            0
2         0               3            0
3         1               4            4
3         1               5            4
```

This solution is a second best but is also fine:

```
Id   flag_testdrive   month_dt   month_testdrive
1         0               1            0
1         0               2            0
1         1               3            3
1         1               4            3
2         0               2            0
2         0               3            0
3         1               4            4
3         1               5            4
```

Comment: Will the data ever have months from different years?

Answer (score 0):

You want `CASE` expression inside  `MIN()`:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN fl_testdrive = 1 THEN month_dt ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY id, flag_testdrive ORDER BY month_dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

Comment: mm with this query I get all 0 if the user doesn't activate the product in the first month he/she is registered :(

Comment: @NicolásAbucharMoya . .  Just remove the `else 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for you:

```
DECLARE @Testdate TABLE(
id INT
,flag_testdrive INT
,month_dt INT
)

INSERT INTO @Testdate (
                          [id]
                        , [flag_testdrive]
                        , [month_dt]
                      )
VALUES(1,0,1)
,(1,0,2)
,(1,1,3)
,(1,1,4)
,(2,0,2)
,(2,0,3)
,(3,1,4)
,(3,1,5)

SELECT
*
,COALESCE((SELECT MIN([aa].[month_dt]) FROM @Testdate aa
                WHERE aa.[id] = a.id
                AND aa.[flag_testdrive] = 1), 0) AS month_testdrive
FROM @Testdate a
```

Return the minimum month_dt for a given id only if flag_testdrive=1, wrapped in coalesce to return 0 instead of NULL.